I cannot edit .navbar, #navbar in CSS
I'm trying to edit the navbar using .navbar and #navbar with CSS and it doesn't work.
I was expecting to edit the navbar from Bootstrap. It doesn't change, I don't know if it is a problem with HTML or CSS, I put the<link rel"stylesheet" href="Style.css"> It works, background-color works, but .navbar or #navbar doesn't work.


#nav-bar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.navbar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517);
}
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.4.2/css/fontawesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="nav-bar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
              
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </section>
</body>




Well this is wrong to start with - background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517);

Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient. Be sure you're following current documentation.

Protip: Don't override core library classes. Create your own semantically-named class and add it to the markup.

As mentioned in the comments your linear-gradient is invalid. Though might not be obviously easy to find, in MDN it did mentioned the color stop list format should be:
<linear-color-stop> , [ <linear-color-hint>? , <linear-color-stop> ]#

This means you need at least one starting color-stop and at least one more color-stop (# sign means one or more). In linear-gradient(to right, #a517) its only given 1 color-stop, hence invalid.
That being said, if you only want one solid background color, use background-color:#a517 instead. Remove bg-body-tertiary as well since it overwrites the customized background color.


#nav-bar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.bg-custom-brown {
  background-color: #a517;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section id="nav-bar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-custom-brown">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>



